# which events does BringToFront() method trigger?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I have two Forms, Form1 and Form2 and I want to do something in Form2 whenever I call Form2.BringToFront() in Form1.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    button1_MouseClick()
    {
        Form2.BringToFront();
        // trigger an event an do something in Form2 
    }
}

class Form2 : Form
{
    UnknownEvent_EventHandler()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

But Documentation on BringToFrontMethod doesn't say which events does this method trigger.

*Notice I don't want to create a public method on Form2 and call it.*

Comment: Have you tried the Move event?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, doesn't work but thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it doesn't fire one directly that I know of, but as a result of its Activation(focus) being changed the Form.Activated Event will fire. You can find the code documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Here is a little sample code:

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //What do you want to happen?
}
```

If this helps you be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: It was a great help. From the link you wrote:


To activate a form at run time using code, call the Activate method. You can use this event for tasks such as updating the contents of the form based on changes made to the form's data when the form was not activated.
That's what I wanted. thanks

Comment: If anyone is curious I used "Activate() method" and "Activated Event" and it worked

Comment: It also worked for me. Thank you. The question was well expressed, and this answer accurately capture what has been asked. Further, a working solution is provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.OpenForms["Form2"].BringToFront();
        }
```

Comment: He wasn't asking how to bring a form to the front. He was asking how to DETECT when a form is brought to the front. I wouln't down-rate, though.

Comment: i apologize :) its a suggestion on how call the other `Form` in that way. any way you can use the `Shown event` -> _(Occurs Whenever the form is first shown)_ or the `Move event` -> _(Occurs when a form is moved)_ but you have to create some logic to complete your task :)

Comment: @JABFreeware do you have any clue to resolve this issue, you are right in your comment and i am facing same issue, so what possibility can be happen in this to detect it?

Answer (score 0):

Its already an older question but as I was running into it too ..

Just add a method in you form / control that brings itself to front and call this method from outside:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    button1_MouseClick()
    {
        instanceOfForm2.ShowInFront();
    }
}

class Form2 : Form
{

    public void ShowInFront()
    {
        this.BringToFront();
        //Do whaterver you want after brought to front
    }
}
```