# Winform controls event when z order changed

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls

I have controls in the same place (one on top of the other)

Is there a way to get an event when the z-order changes?

The purpose is for debugging to see when and who change the order

It can be changed by [`BringToFront`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront?view=netcore-3.1) or  [`SendToBack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback?view=netcore-3.1)  or [`SetChildIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex?view=netcore-3.1)

Like `Control.ZOrderChanged` or `form.Controls.ZOrderChanged`

Comment: There is not such an event, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064067/which-events-does-bringtofront-method-trigger

But why do you need such an event, if you are calling BringToFront()/SendToBack()/SetChildIndex() you can write logic before or after calling those methods, I don't see any point to use an event. in other words, what triggers the Z order to change?

Comment: When the Control receives a `WM_NCPAINT` message, you can check `int childIndex = [Control].Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex([Control])`. It's your code that calls those methods, though. Can you describe what's this for?

Comment: is for debugging to see who change the z-order

Comment: Maybe do a `debug.WriteLine` wherever the z-order is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the *ChildIndex* will trigger a [Layout Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.layout?view=netframework-4.8) on the control that is parent to the child control.  Of course this assumes that [SuspendLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=netframework-4.8) has not been called on the parent control.

You can filter the event by checking the [LayoutEventArgs.AffectedProperty Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.layouteventargs?view=netcore-3.1) (a string) to see if it is equal to "ChildIndex". To determine which control triggered the event, check the [LayoutEventArgs.AffectedControl Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.layouteventargs.affectedcontrol?view=netcore-3.1)