# how to run void after bringtofront panel

Tags: c#

actually I need to call a void when the panel is back to the front, I mean is there any event that checks if the control has been brought to the front?

example:
I have 2 panels every panel has controls so when I make:

```
 panel1.SendToBack();
```

the panel2 will be at the front (here I want to run a specific void).

Comment: Is this `WinForms`? You should tag it properly. In WinForms, the Z-Order is the position of the control in the parent's `Controls` collection (bring-to-front moves the control to the back of the list (so it's drawn last (/on top)). Send-to-back does the opposite

Comment: @Flydog57 can you explain more please?

Comment: @Flydog57 yes it's winforms

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you are talking about better. What do you mean by "run a void"? Are you looking for an event that fires whenever a control's z-order position changes?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436011/winform-controls-event-when-z-order-changed

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that automatically as far as I know, the sendtoback option plays with the z-index of every control, not just the panels. What you should do is create an array that mimics the panels so that you know which panel is where when you look the array (you would also move the array items for this matter). This in order to detect which panel is now at the front, so you can then call the specific void(s) you want